# Flag a record as current using UPDATE with DISTINCT and ORDER

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a table which contains data for properties, each property can have multiple entries which are recorded by date. I want to add a column in the table that flags the current entry to make them easier to select. Something like col name is current_record = Y.

What i've tried;
Creating view which selects just the latest records, then using that view

`UPDATE properties
SET current_record = 'Y'
FROM current_properties
WHERE current_properties.building_reference_number =  properties.building_reference_number;`

With `building_reference_number` indexed on both, with type as integer. This results in a cost of 434537.04 which seems very high. `properties` is 15.6m rows `current_properties` is 12.8m.

I tried a second approach without creating a view as;

`UPDATE properties
SET current_record = 'Y'
WHERE inspection_date IN (
SELECT inspection_date FROM properties
WHERE inspection_date IN (SELECT distinct on (building_reference_number)inspection_date )
ORDER BY inspection_date desc
FOR UPDATE`

But the cost of this is even higher. Here's the explain for the first method, im new to postgres

`Update on properties  (cost=434537.04..4930742.06 rows=15019542 width=608)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=434537.04..4930742.06 rows=15019542 width=608)
        Hash Cond: (properties.building_reference_number = yy_current_epc_dmv.building_reference_number)
        ->  Seq Scan on properties  (cost=0.00..2233904.25 rows=17313725 width=378)
        ->  Hash  (cost=210745.13..210745.13 rows=12874313 width=14)
              ->  Seq Scan on current_properties  (cost=0.00..210745.13 rows=12874313 width=14)`

View definition is;
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (properties.building_reference_number) properties.building_reference_number,
properties.inspection_date
 FROM properties
 ORDER BY properties.building_reference_number, properties.inspection_date DESC;

Comment: You are missing bracket in your second query. Could you post view definition so that we can have idea what is current property? Your second query left me puzzled.

Comment: Have added that now, thanks for looking